# Braintree failed subscription payments retry when updating payment method proration turned on

Tags: braintree, braintree-sandbox

Can someone please help.

Braintree documentation states:

If a payment for a subscription fails, the subscription status will change to Past Due. You can manually retry the charge, or you can set up logic in the Control Panel to automatically retry a declined or failed charge at specific intervals. Additionally, a past due subscription will be automatically retried if the payment method associated with the subscription is updated and you either have proration enabled or are manually passing the prorate charge option. If the retried transaction is successful and the subscription has not passed its last billing date, the status will change to Active.

My question is:

If a payment for a subscription fails, and then the payment method for the subscription is updated with proration turned on a few days later. Will braintree retry the original charge again, or will braintree use proration to charge the customer?

For example:

Customer has a $50 monthly subscription that bills on the first of each month.

Payment fails on 1st September. We email customer and ask them to update payment method.

Customer updates payment method on 3rd September.

Are they charged...

Monthly subscription price = $50

Number of days left in the billing cycle = 27

Total number of days in the billing cycle = 30

($50) x (27 / 30) = $45

Or

Are they charged $50

I would really appreciate any help.